# Wicket - need FilterForm ajax events for GoAndClear button events

Tags: wicket

I've added a FilterForm with GoAndClear buttons to an AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable.  The filtering is working fine except for refreshing my table.  I have a dropdown that changes the number of rows to show which does a target.addComponent(my AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable) which doesn't reload the data but refreshes the.  If I use this after I click a Go or Clear button then the table shows the proper rows, item count, and page links.

How can I handle Go and Clear clicks on my FilterForm to update my AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable?

Answer (score 0):

In the onsubmit method for the filter form just call .renderComponent() for the table.